# To avoid memory leak in corona sdk

Tags: memory-management, coronasdk

I used `spritext()` method for the animation, and I tried  to release the memory of spritesheets by using the `dispose()` method, but it is showing error.

How to release the memory of spritesheets?

```
   local spritext = require("spritext")
   local arr      = {"images/rainbow2.png","images/rainbow1.png"}   

   local myAnim   = spritext.newAnim(arr[1], 600,350, 1, 15);
         myAnim.x = display.contentWidth/2;
         myAnim.y = display.contentHeight/2 -70;
         r:insert(myAnim);

   myAnim:play{ startFrame=1, endFrame=15, loop=1 }

   local function cleanUp()
       myAnim:dispose();
   end
```

Comment: What error is shown? Please clarify and be more descriptive so that others can actually help...

Comment: the error is,attempt to call method 'dispose'<a nil value>

Comment: Without any code we cannot help you...

Comment: Update your question, don't post code inside a comment...

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the API for SpriteSheet? I believe that object:dispose is deprecated.

The new way of using it is via SpriteObject, and it inherits from the DisplayObject API.
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/SpriteObject/index.html - SpriteObject

You should able to call object:removeSelf from the DisplayObject API. http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/removeSelf.html

Here is a snippet of how I handle my spritesheets.

```
-- Import sprite sheet
local someSheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "someimages.png", someInfo:getSheet() ) -- ImageSheet.png is the image Texture packer published

-- Set sprite sequence data.
local someSequenceData = {
     { name="dance", frames={8,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,8}, time=2000, loopCount=1},
     { name="sad", frames={8,9,8}, time=3000, loopCount=1},
     { name="happy", frames={8,5,8}, time=3000, loopCount=1},
     { name="smile", frames={8,10,8}, time=3000, loopCount=1},
     { name="hit", frames={7,8}, time=2000, loopCount=1}
}

-- load sprite object
spriteObject = display.newSprite( someSheet, someSequenceData )
spriteObject.x = display.contentWidth/2
spriteObject.y = display.contentHeight/2

-- play one of the animations
spriteObject:play("dance")

-- to remove the entire sprite object
spriteObject:removeSelf()
```

A quick note:
For my spritesheets I use a application called "TexturePacker", I just drop some images in, set some settings, and then it builds a packed sprite sheet, along with a data sheet to go along with it.

EDIT:
I didn't realize this question is rather old.. Oh well. I hope this helps someone out anyway. :P